# jq - pipe multiple files from "find" to jq

Tags: find, pipe, jq

I try to get all versions of a specific node-package within a project nodes_module folder.

There are multiple package.json files and I wish to "grep" the ones under "dependencies": { "package-name" }

example json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-package": "^1.1.1",
    "some-package": "^1.0.1",
    "the-package-i-am-looking-for": "1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "some-package": "^1.7.3",
    "some-package": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

I would like to know the filename and the line (therefor grep)

so ideally the output would look like this

```
some-package/package.json: "the-package-i-am-looking-for": "1.2.3"
some-other-package/package.json: "the-package-i-am-looking-for": "2.3.4"
```

I'm new to the hole unix piping. this is what I came up with - which obviously does not work

`find . -name package.json | xargs cat | jq '.dependencies' | grep '"the-package-i-am-looking-for"'`

Thankful for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that none of the parts of your pipeline, downstream from `cat`, has access to the original file's name. From `cat` onward, it's just data consisting of the contents of one or several files that arrives on the pipe.

I *believe* that the following may be something like what you're looking for:

```bsh
find . -type f -name package.json \
    -exec jq -r --arg pkg 'the-package-i-am-looking-for' \
        '.dependencies | .[$pkg] // empty | [input_filename,$pkg,.] | @tsv' {} +
```

This outputs a tab-delimited list consisting of three fields:

1. The pathname of the file where the package was found.
2. The package name.
3. The version string.

The `find` command calls `jq` with *batches* of found pathnames to produce the output, so that as few `jq` invocations as possible are done. It's the `{} +` at the end of `-exec` that will be replaced by the collected filenames.

The `jq` call produces the output by parsing the input file(s), extracting the `.dependencies` value, getting the version string for the key corresponding to the package we're looking for, and if something was found, outputting the current filename, the package name that we are querying with, and the version string itself, as a tab-delimited list using `@tsv`.

The output format could be modified to suit your needs. You could change `@tsv` into `@csv` to get CSV-formatted output.

Example with copy of the provided file (with formatting issus corrected) in the current directory and in the directory called `dir`:

```bsh
$ tree
.
|-- dir
|   `-- package.json
`-- package.json

1 directory, 2 files
```

```bsh
$ find . -type f -name package.json -exec jq -r --arg pkg 'the-package-i-am-looking-for' -e '.dependencies | .[$pkg] // empty | [input_filename,$pkg,.] | @tsv' {} +
./package.json  the-package-i-am-looking-for    1.2.3
./dir/package.json      the-package-i-am-looking-for    1.2.3
```

---

If you felt like you really need a pipeline between `find` and `xargs`, you could use the following non-portable code:

```bsh
find . -type f -name package.json -print0 |
xargs -0 \
    jq -r --arg pkg 'the-package-i-am-looking-for' \
        '.dependencies | .[$pkg] // empty | [input_filename,$pkg,.] | @tsv'
```

You gain nothing by doing it this way compared to doing it all from `find` directly.